# Time given to fix the problem

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In a biblical passage I am studying, I noticed that the accused was given a short span of time in order to fix the problem he had caused.  This idea (granting time to correct the situation) is important for my study and I want to include it in the index.  Is there a word (or short two word phrase) that has this meaning?

Comment: What book & verse?

Comment: Luke 16:1-12 The Parable of the Unjust Steward.

Comment: Although I don't interpret the passage ("2 And he called him and said to him, ‘What is this that I hear about you? Turn in the account of your management, for you can no longer be manager.’ 3 And the manager said to himself, ‘What shall I do, since my master is taking the management away from me?") as offering the manager a respite or grace period, I'll answer below as if it does.

Comment: Perhaps "given a time span" isn't a good description of what happened in the parable.  I'm studying accountability as it relates to parenting.  In the KJV that I was reading, the end of verse 2 reads, "for thou mayest no longer..."  which, on my first reading sounded like the consequences were not definite yet.  So, when the manager attempts to fix the problem, the employer says he did well.  That's where the idea of a grace period (again, think 'parenting') came from.  Giving children time to correct the problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might want to try **[grace period](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/grace+period)**, which, since you are talking about a bible passage, would have a nice double entendre.

Comment: Absolutely. If you Google **car tax grace period** you'll find a vast number of entries relating to the popular misconception that DVLA (UK Driver and Vehicle Licensing Agency) allows you to keep your car on the road for up to 14 days after the tax disc has expired. I never heard of *remedial period*, which NGramp indicates is [exceptionally rare by comparison](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=remedial+period%2Cgrace+period&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is legally referred to as a ***remedial period***.

An example of this usage can be found in [this recent amendment](http://www.ccda.ca.gov/res/docs/pdf/HR-881.pdf) to the Americans with Disabilities Act.

Comment: Thanks!  I wasn't aware of this legal phrase.  I selected the other answer simply because it seemed to fit with the biblical context a little better.

Answer (score 2):

***notice***

A person may be put on *notice*, for a definite or indefinite period, generally implying the consequences of not complying with and probably also the salutary effect of compliance.

A delinquent employee is put on *notice* that if does not rectify the situation, action would automatically follow. The notice period may form part of the notice, the completion of which without the condition being fulfilled satisfactorily would trigger consequential action.

Answer (score 2):

Why not the word **"Deadline"**? That also refers to time limit given for completion of a task right?

deadline [ˈdɛdˌlaɪn]
n
a time limit for any activity

Answer (score 1):

Consider *[hang time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hang_time)*, "how long something stays in the air" to describe the brief interval between when a manager is fired and actually escorted off the premises.  One meaning noted in Wikipedia is "In some first-person shooters, the length of time a player flies through the air as the result of a grenade jump".

Also see *delay* [synonyms](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/search?b=1&r=delay&send=Look+it+up), which include *deferment, moratorium, postponement, reprieve, stay*, and some of their [synonyms](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/search?b=1&r=postponement&send=Look+it+up) in turn, like *suspension*, with useful [synonyms](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/search?b=1&r=suspension) in turn like *[hiatus](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/search?b=1&r=hiatus)*, *[abeyance](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/search?b=1&r=abeyance)*, and more.